# Re-download apps with second computer/device

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, apple-id

My situation:

I have an iPhone with synced to my computer and my wife just bought an iPad (in shipment) which she will sync to her computer.

We want to use my Apple ID on both computers/devices so that she can use apps and music I have already purchased. Syncing the devices to the same computer is not an option.

Is this an option, and how would it work, i.e., would she have to "purchase" and get a message saying it has already been purchased, and to re-download?

Thanks!

Comment: On stuffs from apple, just be sure to always read the warnings on any action you do and this questions shouldn't even be needed. I'm saying that with the "[merge issue](http://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-mac)" in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be a problem; you can use the same Apple ID on up to five computers. If the two computers are on the same network, you can use Home Sharing in iTunes to make sharing easier; otherwise, your wife can sign in with your Apple ID, and re-download the stuff that she wants.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I'll accept when we get it, try it and confirm.

Comment: This answer, whilst correct at the time of writing, is no longer the recommended way to achieve this. Family Sharing, detailed in another answer, is now the way to do it - without getting cross-pollination of email, iMessages etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the option of [Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/family-sharing/) that Apple introduced in iOS 8.

This allows you to share apps, music, and other purchases while still being able to maintain separate Apple ID's for other purposes.